# NestJS / Typeorm preload cache

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a table I want to load once right after Nest starts and the database is connected
I can't seem to find an event for TypeORM for db - is Connected, and when I try
`getConnection` I get a warning, and right now I solved this in a poor timeout po

```
const f = () => {
    const con = getConnection();
    if (con.isConnected) {
        console.log('connected');
        // this is where the table load will take place
    } else {
        console.error('not connected');
        setTimeout(() => {
            f();
        }, 200);
    }
};
f();
```

that results in `"ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found."`

so I wonder if there's anyway around it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case someone else needs that - the answer (for me) was in NestJS - using `OnApplicationBootstrap`
which led to this code running after everything was initialized

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  async onApplicationBootstrap() {
    const all = await Configuration.find();
    console.log('all?', all.length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `createConnection()` instead of `getConnection()`.

`getConnection()` gets a connection already created using `createConnection()`.

`createConnection()` returns a promise which you can await, or you can call your callback with `createConnection().then(...)`. The promise resolves after the connection successfully connects, or rejects if it fails to connect.

See [TypeOrm connection API](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/connection-api.md) for more.